# {purrr}: how to replace a simple loop with `purrr::map()` while using up all arguments of a function?

Tags: r, purrr

*Hi all, I've read the help file and quite a few questions on the topic here but couldn't find* *an answer. I believe it is a very simple question, so I am likely missing something obvious.*

I would like to replace such a basic `for loop` implementation, such as

```
lst <- list()
for (i in 1:10) {
  lst[[i]] <- rnorm(n = 3, mean = 5, sd = 3)
}
lst
```

with `purrr::map()`, while using up all arguments of the function (here: `rnorm()`)

The following doesn't work and returns an `unused argument` error.

```
1:10 %>%
  map(rnorm, n = 3, mean = 5, sd = 3)
# Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : unused argument (.x[[i]])
```

The following runs, but map passed the arguments `1:10` to `rnorm(sd = .x)`, so
the result is not what expected.

```
library(purrr)
1:3 %>% 
  map(rnorm, n = 3, mean = 5)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 5.133702 6.456135 5.041438
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 5.722486 4.614772 2.640809
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 1.445749 5.826666 6.096497
```

Is there a simple way of achieving that?

*I appreciate your time and attention.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this. The first is an anonymous function and the second is a formula. Refer to the examples in `?map()` for more information.

1. Anonymous Function

   ```
   library(purrr)
   1:10 %>%
     map(function(x) rnorm(n = 3, mean = 5, sd = 3))
   ```
2. Formula

   ```
   1:10 %>%
     map(~ rnorm(n = 3, mean = 5, sd = 3))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `for` loop and/or `map` but I think this is more of `replicate` or `purrr::rerun` problem.

In base R :

```
replicate(10, rnorm(n = 3, mean = 5, sd = 3), simplify = FALSE)
```

Or using `purrr` :

```
purrr::rerun(10, rnorm(n = 3, mean = 5, sd = 3))
```